# How to create an empty object which has defined value type

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I'm trying to create an object that has string type keys and the values are objects of a class I defined.

an example would be:

```
let rockHardObs = {
    'Lady': { 
        'Rah': new  Gaga('rah-ah-ah-ah'),
        'Roma': new  Gaga('roma-ma')
    }
}
```

So I want to just initialize it with an empty object corresponding to the key `'Lady'` like this.

```
let rockHardObs = {
    'Lady': { string : Gaga }
}
```

Comment: Check out Typescript Interfaces. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html

Comment: you can use typescript interface. only if you are using typescript

Comment: Check out Typescript Interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an empty object literal and a type assertion to tell the compiler what the expected type of the property will be:

```
let rockHardObs = {
    'Lady': { } as { [key: string]: Gaga }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let rockHardObs: {
    [key?: "Lady"]: { [key: string] : Gaga }
} = {}
```

Comment: Either Lady should be optional or the object should be instantiated.

Comment: `'lady'?` would be better ;)

Comment: My key Lady isn't optional, in fact, the value against 'Lady' has to be initialized. @Titian's answer is what I was looking for. But do Keep your answer the way it is, and edit it to show the situation where we can use your answer. It's something i would have gotten stuck on later.